# PyPDF2: merging PDF files

Tags: python, beginner

I sometimes need to merge some big PDF files. Looking around I decided to use PyPDF2. All files are in the same directory as the script. The code works as intended and was tested with 5 small PDF files.

I found many variations and decided to write this one myself:

```
import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


files = sorted(glob.glob('./*.pdf'))
merger = PdfFileMerger()
filename = input("Enter merged file name: ")

for file in files:
    merger.append(file)
    print(f"Processed file {file}")

merger.write(f'{filename}.pdf')
merger.close()
```

All files have titles such as `1.pdf` `2.pdf`.

The writing to file bit seems sloppy to me but I don't know how to or even if to improve it. Did I insure that the files list will always be in alphabetical order? Are there best practice things I missed? Any other feedback is welcome as well.

The code only needs to run on windows. Cross-platform is not a concern for me. I don't anticipate memory constraints as the system it runs on has a lot of RAM. This will only run client side using Python 3.8.

Comment: Minor point, you don't have consistent quotes